# How to programmatically check WCF Http/Non-Http Activation components?

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, wix

I need to detect if WCF Http/Non-Http Activation Components is installed during the installation of my product. How can I do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For IIS7, check the following Registry Key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\Components\

For the following components:

- Process Model - ProcessModel
- .NET Environment - NetFxEnvironment
- Configuration APIs - WASConfigurationAPI

From this page:  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/135/discover-installed-components/

**UPDATE:** Since the above is true even when the components are not installed, try running this command from the command line:

sc query nettcpactivator

If the service is stopped or does not exist, the WCF Non-HTTP Activation components are likely not installed.  To install them, run this command:

pkgmgr /iu: WCF-NonHTTP-Activation

Source:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2010/05/11/debugging-a-missing-hostedtransportconfiguration-type.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not helpful. These three values exist in registry (and equal 1) independently of the http/non-http activation components are installed. (Windows Server 2008R2)

Comment: How about checking to see if the "Windows Process Activation Service" exists and the status is Started?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and write about the results. )

Comment: Good! It is exactly what I need! Thank you, Darrel!

Answer (score 3):

For IIS8 with Windows Server 2012 (and probably Windows 8), you can check this registry key (for .NET 4.5)

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ServerManager\ServicingStorage\ServerComponentCache\NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45\InstallState`

zero means not installed, and 1 means installed.

Comment: The key exists for 2012, but not for Windows 8

Answer (score 3):

You also can use PowerShell to enable WCF Http/Non-Http Activation components:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature NET-HTTP-Activation,NET-Non-HTTP-Activ
```

This way you do not have to mess up with Windows Registry. For more info about adding Windows feature with PowerShell: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732263.aspx#BKMK_powershell

Answer (score 1):

The registry key for HTTP activation is:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup\Windows Communication Foundation\HTTPActivation`

, and for `non-HTTP` activation is checking whether the service `NetTcpActivation` or `NetPipeActivator` exist on the machine and are running.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the Get-WindowsFeature powershell commandlet.  You can check the existence on Server 2012 of .NET Framework 4.5 WCF Services for HTTP Activation by calling:

```
$wcfActivationFeature = Get-WindowsFeature -name NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45
$wcfActivationFeature.Installed
```